# Convert excel print page to pdf and send to email on the print page

Tags: excel, vba, email-attachments, pdf-conversion

I'd like to make a VBA code in excel but I'm stuck. I want it to take my worksheet where I have several pages to print (50 pages in one worksheet).

On every print page there is a sum and if that sum is greater than 0 I want to convert that page to a pdf and send the print page to the email on the page (so it's different emails).

The sum is in `F22` and email is in `B8` on page 1.

The sum is in `F72` and email is in `B58` on page 2.

So the range changes by 50 rows every page.

The emails area is `B2:F50` on first page and `B52:F100` on second page, `B102:F150` on the third.

I have tried but can only do it with 1 page and 1 email.
here is the code i have, work for 1 page

```
Sub RDB_Selection_Range_To_PDF_And_Create_Mail()
Dim Charge As Integer
Charge = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Crosscharge").Cells(23, 6).Value
If Charge > 0 Then
    Dim FileName As String

    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "There is more then one sheet selected," & vbNewLine & _
               "ungroup the sheets and try the macro again"
    Else
        'Call the function with the correct arguments
        'For a fixed range use this line
        FileName = RDB_Create_PDF(Source:=Range("B2:F50"), _
                                  FixedFilePathName:="", _
                                  OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                                  OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)

        If FileName <> "" Then
            RDB_Mail_PDF_Outlook FileNamePDF:=FileName, _
                                 StrTo:="Email", _
                                 StrCC:="", _
                                 StrBCC:="", _
                                 StrSubject:="Text", _
                                 Signature:=True, _
                                 Send:=False, _
                                 StrBody:="<H3><B>Dear Customer</B></H3><br>" & _
                                          "<body>See the attached PDF file with the." & _
                                          "<br><br>" & "Kind regards</body>"
        Else
            MsgBox "Not possible to create the PDF, possible reasons:" & vbNewLine & _
                   "Microsoft Add-in is not installed" & vbNewLine & _
                   "You Canceled the GetSaveAsFilename dialog" & vbNewLine & _
                   "The path to Save the file in arg 2 is not correct" & vbNewLine & _
                   "You didn't want to overwrite the existing PDF if it exist"

        End If

End If
```

End Sub

Hope you can help

Comment: Please post the code you have gotten working for one page and one email so that we can help you modify it to work for multiple ranges.

Comment: Please provide the code you worked.

Comment: I have added my code to the original questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is implement a loop. The fact that your cells are exactly 50 apart for each page makes this very easy for your code. Another note that I see if that you assign the value in cell `F23` to an `Integer` at the very beginning. Unless you can guarantee that it will always be an integer (for example you're rounding) it might be better to define it as `Double` Also the `Integer` type can only hold numbers between ~ - 2 billion and 2 billion. If you might be dealing with numbers larger then that use `Long`.

I was unable to test this code in it's entirety because you call on some custom functions, but try this. If there are any issues let me know and I will update this code.

```
Sub RDB_Selection_Range_To_PDF_And_Create_Mail()
Dim Charge As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Long

LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "There is more then one sheet selected," & vbNewLine & _
               "ungroup the sheets and try the macro again"
End If

i = 23

Do While i <= LastRow

    Charge = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Crosscharge").Cells(i, 6).Value
    If Charge > 0 Then
        'Call the function with the correct arguments
        'For a fixed range use this line
        FileName = RDB_Create_PDF(Source:=Range("B2:F" & i + 27), _
                                      FixedFilePathName:="", _
                                      OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                                      OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)

        If FileName <> "" Then
                RDB_Mail_PDF_Outlook FileNamePDF:=FileName, _
                                     StrTo:="Email", _
                                     StrCC:="", _
                                     StrBCC:="", _
                                     StrSubject:="Text", _
                                     Signature:=True, _
                                     Send:=False, _
                                     StrBody:="<H3><B>Dear Customer</B></H3><br>" & _
                                              "<body>See the attached PDF file with the." & _
                                              "<br><br>" & "Kind regards</body>"
        Else
            MsgBox "Not possible to create the PDF, possible reasons:" & vbNewLine & _
                   "Microsoft Add-in is not installed" & vbNewLine & _
                   "You Canceled the GetSaveAsFilename dialog" & vbNewLine & _
                   "The path to Save the file in arg 2 is not correct" & vbNewLine & _
                   "You didn't want to overwrite the existing PDF if it exist"

        End If

    End If
i = i + 50
Loop
End Sub
```